How do I use child routes in angular 17 angular routing
How do I create child routes for a tab page using angular?
app.component.html
<main class="main">
  <div class="content container-fluid">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-header [hidden]="!this.headerIsHidden"></app-header>
    <app-job-details [hidden]="!this.jobDetailsIsHidden"></app-job-details>
    <app-notification-details [hidden]="!this.notificationDetailsIsHidden"></app-notification-details>
  </div>
</main>

header.component.html
<div class="background">
    <p class="text-center">Job Tracker</p>
    <p-tabView class="tab"  [hidden]="isHidden" (onChange)="handleChange($event)" [(activeIndex)]="headerIndex">
        <p-tabPanel header="View Jobs Applied For">
           <app-job-applied-for></app-job-applied-for>
        </p-tabPanel>
        <p-tabPanel header="Add Job Applied For">
            <app-add-job-applied-for></app-add-job-applied-for>
        </p-tabPanel>
        <p-tabPanel header="Remove Job Applied For">
         <app-remove-job-applied-for></app-remove-job-applied-for>
        </p-tabPanel>
        <p-tabPanel header="View Notification" [disabled]="notificationsIsDisabled">
          <app-view-notification></app-view-notification>
        </p-tabPanel>
        <p-tabPanel header="Set Notification" [disabled]="notificationsIsDisabled">
          <app-set-notification></app-set-notification>
        </p-tabPanel>
        <p-tabPanel header="Remove Notification" [disabled]="notificationsIsDisabled">
          <app-remove-notification></app-remove-notification>
        </p-tabPanel>
    </p-tabView>
</div>

app.routes.ts
export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'app-header', component: HeaderComponent, children:[
        { path: '',redirectTo: 'app-header', pathMatch: 'full'},
        { path: 'app-job-applied-for', component: JobAppliedForComponent},
        { path: 'app-add-job-applied-for', component: AddJobAppliedForComponent},
        { path: 'app-remove-job-applied-for', component: RemoveJobAppliedForComponent},
        { path: 'app-view-notification', component: ViewNotificationComponent},
        { path: 'app-set-notification', component: SetNotificationComponent},
        { path: 'app-remove-notification', component: RemoveNotificationComponent},
    ]},
    { path: 'app-job-details', component: JobDetailsComponent  },
    { path: 'app-job-details/:id', component: JobDetailsComponent  },
    { path: 'app-notification-details', component: NotificationDetailsComponent  },
    { path: 'app-notification-details/:id', component: NotificationDetailsComponent  },
    { path: 'app-edit-job', component: EditJobComponent  },
    { path: 'app-edit-job/:id', component: EditJobComponent  },
    { path: 'app-edit-notification', component: EditNotificationComponent  },
    { path: 'app-edit-notification/:id', component: EditNotificationComponent  }
];

when I remove all child routes except for the first child route, the header page displays, I can navigate to all tabs, but I don't have routing for the other tabs. When I add router outlet to the header component, I don't get an error in the console, but routing doesn't work either(i get a blank screen). When I try to running it without adding a routeroutlet to the header, and leaving all paths in tack, I get this error:

I strongly believe the issue is in app.routes.ts, but I don't know how to fix it. What do I need to do to get child routing working?
Code post here if anyone wants to give it a shot

are your versions of angular packages aligned? that eror means that componenents weren't properly compiled

Update
There is a lot of stuff which needs to be corrected, will just run through few of them, you need to go to Angular docs and give a good read.

You should import a service/component using private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, this will do the importing automatically, so you can get rid of the extra code inside the constructor, since it's automatically taken care of in the constructor.

You should not import all the components/services instead, you should only import when an error comes, the main thing to know is that, if the component is from routing, there is no need to import it.

Instead of importing component in the constructor (tight coupling), use @Input and @Output also when routing is involved you need to use event bus, reference stackblitz, always aim for loose coupling, since the component cannot work freely without the parent due to dependency.

You should only have one boostrapApplication in your code.

You should create a module which contains the imports shared by multiple components, make sure the imports are used everywhere in your application, these eases the work of importing multiple times.

For the routing, you should have a <router-outlet/> below the tabs.

You should navigate using relative to activated route.
 this.router.navigate(['./', routingMap[event.index]], {
   relativeTo: this.activatedRoute
 })


You should get rid of the route contents since it's already taken care of by routing.
 <div class="background">
   <p class="text-center">Job Tracker</p>
   <p-tabView
     class="tab"
     [hidden]="isHidden"
     (onChange)="handleChange($event)"
     [(activeIndex)]="headerIndex"
   >
     <p-tabPanel header="View Jobs Applied For"> </p-tabPanel>
     <p-tabPanel header="Add Job Applied For"> </p-tabPanel>
     <p-tabPanel header="Remove Job Applied For"> </p-tabPanel>
     <p-tabPanel header="View Notification"> </p-tabPanel>
     <p-tabPanel header="Set Notification"> </p-tabPanel>
     <p-tabPanel header="Remove Notification"> </p-tabPanel>
   </p-tabView>
   <router-outlet />
 </div>


Finally, the routing should have default redirects so that the end user, does not end up in a blank screen when first loading the application.
 export const routes: Routes = [
     { path: '', redirectTo: 'app-header', pathMatch: 'full' },
     {
         path: 'app-header', component: HeaderComponent, children: [
             { path: '', redirectTo: 'app-job-applied-for', pathMatch: 'full' },
             { path: 'app-job-applied-for', component: JobAppliedForComponent },
             { path: 'app-add-job-applied-for', component: AddJobAppliedForComponent },
             { path: 'app-remove-job-applied-for', component: RemoveJobAppliedForComponent },
             { path: 'app-view-notification', component: ViewNotificationComponent },
             { path: 'app-set-notification', component: SetNotificationComponent },
             { path: 'app-remove-notification', component: RemoveNotificationComponent },

         ]
     },
     { path: 'app-job-details', component: JobDetailsComponent },
     { path: 'app-job-details/:id', component: JobDetailsComponent },
     { path: 'app-notification-details', component: NotificationDetailsComponent },
     { path: 'app-notification-details/:id', component: NotificationDetailsComponent },
     { path: 'app-edit-job', component: EditJobComponent },
     { path: 'app-edit-job/:id', component: EditJobComponent },
     { path: 'app-edit-notification', component: EditNotificationComponent },
     { path: 'app-edit-notification/:id', component: EditNotificationComponent }
 ];



Github Repo



The error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading "ecmp")" is related to you using a component that is not imported/declared.

I think the issue is due to one of the components (JobAppliedForComponent, AddJobAppliedForComponent, RemoveJobAppliedForComponent, RemoveJobAppliedForComponent, ViewNotificationComponent, SetNotificationComponent, RemoveNotificationComponent)
If you application follows standalone methodology
Validate that the above mentioned components have standalone: true set on them, only then the components will be discovered by routing.

If you application follows modular methodology
Validate that the above mentioned components are added to the declarations array of the AppModule, only then routing can discover these components.

standalone: true is default behavior. I didn't change the defaulted behavior. All pages work without nested routing. But when the routing is nested, it doesn't work.

I posted a github here if you would like to download it and see what the issue is. What I was trying to do is go back from the edit notification page to the view notification page after a notification was edited. Same for the job. But I was having issue with the navigation.

@Daron updated my answer, don't merge my branch before inspecting the changes, I removed some code for debugging, which you need to check and revert.

thank you very much.... i am looked at it now and i will update you very shortly

the root level navigation is broken (app-job-details, app-notification-details, app-edit-job, app-edit-notification) in the branch you created and the active tabs are not being selected on navigation using code... But you definitely solved the main issue that I was having with nested routing... I think you have given me enough to work with that i should be able to fix those minor issues. Thank alot!

i think i understand what the issue was based on what you posted here.... I think the issue was P-tabPanel is a component, so I should not have been putting my component inside of a P-tabPanel component. Based on your changes, that seems like that was my issue.

Don’t need to redirect to 'app-header' within its own child routes. Instead, you can either set a default child route to one of the tabs or remove the default redirect.
export const routes: Routes = [
    { 
        path: 'app-header', 
        component: HeaderComponent, 
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'app-job-applied-for', pathMatch: 'full'}, // Default to the first tab
            { path: 'app-job-applied-for', component: JobAppliedForComponent },
            { path: 'app-add-job-applied-for', component: AddJobAppliedForComponent },
            { path: 'app-remove-job-applied-for', component: RemoveJobAppliedForComponent },
            { path: 'app-view-notification', component: ViewNotificationComponent },
            { path: 'app-set-notification', component: SetNotificationComponent },
            { path: 'app-remove-notification', component: RemoveNotificationComponent },
        ]
    },
    { path: 'app-job-details', component: JobDetailsComponent },
    { path: 'app-job-details/:id', component: JobDetailsComponent },
    { path: 'app-notification-details', component: NotificationDetailsComponent },
    { path: 'app-notification-details/:id', component: NotificationDetailsComponent },
    { path: 'app-edit-job', component: EditJobComponent },
    { path: 'app-edit-job/:id', component: EditJobComponent },
    { path: 'app-edit-notification', component: EditNotificationComponent },
    { path: 'app-edit-notification/:id', component: EditNotificationComponent }
];


The idea under a child routes are to have some like
  <router-outlet> 
     ..here you have a component
     ..in your component you have another
     <router-outlet>
     </router-outlet>
  </router-outlet>

See that the first one router-outlet are replaced by the header-component and the children go into the router-outlet inside the header-component.
You have not this construction, you have a "header-component" with a tabView
You can use a tabView with the "p-tabPanel" emptys an to have a router-outlet and use activeIndexChange
<p-tabView (activeIndexChange)="navigate($event)">
    <p-tabPanel header="Header I" >
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header II">
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header III">
    </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

And
constructor(private router:Router){}
navigate(index:any)
{
    switch(index)
    {
        case 0:
            this.router.navigate(['/first-component'])
            break;
        case 1:
            this.router.navigate(['/second-component'])
            break;
        case 2:
            this.router.navigate(['/third-component'])
            break;
    }
}

stackblitz
Update well, ther're a problem that it's when we navigate to a component in other ways taht use the tabview.
So, first we are declare a variable activeIndex so we have
<p-tabView [(activeIndex)]="activeIndex" 
            (activeIndexChange)="navigate($event)">
...
</p-tabView>

And in ngOnInit we subscribe to router.events in the way
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.router.events
      .pipe(filter((event: any) => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        const route = this.router.config.find(
          (x: any) => '/' + x.path == res.url
        );
        if (route.data.index != this.activeIndex)
          this.activeIndex = route.data.index;
      });
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription && this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

NOTE: I use the way this.router.config.find((x: any) => '/' + x.path == res.url); to avoid a large switch. And we define the routes like
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'first-component', component: OneComponent, data: { index: 0 } },
  { path: 'second-component', component: TwoComponent, data: { index: 1 } },
  { path: 'third-component', component: ThirdComponent, data: { index: 2 } },
];

In the stackblitz, from component three we can navigate to component one

This issue isn't that i can't switch tabs... the issue is a nested router issue. I did give this solution a try but it didn't work.

I posted a github here if you would like to download it and see what the issue is. What I was trying to do is go back from the edit notification page to the view notification page after a notification was edited. Same for the job. But I was having issue with the navigation.
